# How to specify custom metadata in resumable upload (via XML API)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am following steps for resumable upload outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-resumable).

According to documentation custom metadata has to be specified in first `POST` and is to be passed via `x-goog-meta-*` headers. I.e.:

```
x-goog-meta-header1: value1
x-goog-meta-header2: value2
... etc
```

But in my testing all these values disappear. After final `PUT` object shows up in the bucket with proper `content-type` but without a single piece of custom metadata.

What I am doing wrong?

P.S. It is rather suspicious that JSON API in resumable upload takes metadata as payload of first `POST`...

P.P.S. I am performing resumable upload via XML API described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads#xml-api) (only using C++ code instead of `curl` utility). Adding `x-goog-meta-mykey: myvalue` header has no effect on object's custom metadata.

Comment: What headers do you need to attach to the object metadata? List those in your question with the code as you might be defining them wrong.

Comment: @JohnHanley Doesn't matter. `header1=value1` for example

Comment: You know best, but some headers are not allowed and are stripped out of requests. When posting questions, try to create questions that benefit everyone. As written there are not enough details to provide a good answer. For your PS, the first step is to create the session. I think it makes sense to craft the object at that point. The following data upload then does not need to repeat the headers.

Comment: @JohnHanley I can make it anymore clear. I've created a `POST` request according to Google's documentation where it explains where custom metadata should go. I've followed every step, `POST` gives me sessions URI, then sequence of `PUT`s using that URI. At the end -- object gets created with correct data, but without my custom metadata. I don't repeat anything -- metadata is specified in initial `POST` only. It looks like a bug in either documentation or GCS.

Comment: I have written code many times and it works. So has many customers. I am not aware of a bug, but it is possible. However, I do not have a crystal ball and I cannot see your code or reproduce your problem based upon the details in your question. If you believe it is a bug, post the details here. https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker

Comment: @JohnHanley Maybe it works for others because everyone else is using JSON API? I'll try to come up with a `curl`-based repro... I am using HMAC keys (and signed URL) instead of OAuth2, who knows, maybe this is the culprit.

Comment: I use both the XML and JSON API in C++ and other languages (PHP, Python, C#/.NET). The XML API was created to be S3 compatible. I recommend switching to the JSON API and using OAuth authorization. The XML API is legacy but still there for compatibility. As you might guess if the XML API had this bug, a lot of third-party vendors would be screaming.

Comment: It is working for me, this is what I did with pure `curl` commands:

 https://gist.github.com/coryan/b0813cddf41bfc1acbc9c90a39005c8d

I did notice that the `x-goog-meta-*` field is not included in the response to the last `PUT`, I am not sure if that should be expected.

Comment: @JohnHanley @coryan I figured it out -- if `Authorization` header starts with `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256` GCS expects `x-amz-*` headers (and ignores `x-goog-meta-*`). Exception is made for `x-goog-resumable`. Problem is that specifying `x-amz-meta-*` in initial `POST` causes request to fail (it complains about mixing `x-goog-` and `x-amz-` headers). Solution is to use `GOOG1-HMAC-SHA256` instead -- it magically works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you replace `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256` in `Authorization` header with `GOOG4-HMAC-SHA256` -- it works. GCS uses this bit as a "should I expect `x-amz-` or `x-goog-` headers?" switch. Problem is that with resumable upload you **have** to specify `x-goog-resumable` and adding `x-amz-meta-*` headers causes request to fail with a message about mixing `x-goog-` and `x-amz-` headers.

I also went ahead and changed few other aspects of signature, namely:

- request type: `aws4_request` -> `goog4_request`
- signing key: `AWS4` -> `GOOG4` (`GOOG1` works too)
- service name: `s3` -> `storage` (even though in some errors GCS asks for either `s3` or `storage` to be specified here, it also takes `gcs` and maybe other values)

... this isn't necessary, it seems. I've done it just for consistency.